# Add line to text file and save in php

Tags: php

With this script, I create a text file, sorted according to my needs, but I would need to add a line at the beginning of the file to add a comment and save it to a new file with php extension, how can I do?

```
$txt = "file.txt";
    $weights = array(
"Example 1"=>200,
"Example 2"=>199,
"Example 3"=>198,
"Example 4"=>197,
"Example 5"=>196);

  $righi = file($txt);
    foreach($righi as $id => $player){
  list($name, $position) = explode(">", $player);
  $weighted[$weights[trim($position)]] = trim($player);
}

//sort by keys (reverse order ... descending)
krsort($weighted);

//output to screen
echo implode("<br>",$weighted);

//overwrite original file
file_put_contents($txt, implode(PHP_EOL, $weighted));
```

this is the output

```
<a href='http://www.example.com/Example 1.txt'>Example 1
<a href='http://www.example.com/Example 2.txt''>Example 2
<a href='http://www.example.com/Example 3.txt''>Example 3
<a href='http://www.example.com/Example 4.txt''>Example 4
<a href='http://www.example.com/Example 5.txt''>Example 5
```

Comment: can you share the sample output of your file?

Comment: `file_put_contents($txt, $comment . implode(PHP_EOL, $weighted));` ?

Comment: Perfect, thank you, but to save such as test.php, how can I do?

Comment: i don't understand the problem :(

Comment: Be patient but they are just a beginner, after I override script file.txt, but I would have two copies, before and after the change, so I would be able to save such as file.php but I can not figure out how.

Comment: I settled with a rename. Thank you